# Can random_number() generate NAN?

Tags: fortran

Can the function `random_number()` generate a NAN in Fortran?
If, for instance, I have a real*8 array called A, and I call function `random_number(A)` - can any A element (result) be a NAN?

Answer (score 4):

No.

According to the Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 13.7.135 "RANDOM NUMBER (HARVEST)":

> **Argument.** HARVEST shall be of type real. It is an INTENT (OUT) argument. It may be a scalar or an array.
>   It is assigned pseudorandom numbers from the uniform distribution in the interval 0 ≤ x < 1.